# Pass the arguments as string not variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck at calling `onclick` function.. here is the code..

```
    $(function() {
        $.each(json, function(i, item) {
            var row = '<tr>' +
                '<td>' + item.id + '</td>' +
                '<td class="project-title"><a onclick="loadData(' + item.id + ', ' + item.name + ', ' + item.description + ')">' + item.name +
                '</a></td>' +
                '<td>' + item.description +
                '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $('#Table tbody').append(row);
        });
    });
```

The issue here is that while executing the `loadData` function second and third arguments are not taken as string instead it takes as variable.

```
loadData(1, Sam, Subscriber)
```

> Error: ReferenceError: Sam is not defined

I need both to be passed as string (i.e. value of the `name: Sam` and `description: Subscriber`) not as a variable.

Ex.

```
loadData(1, "Sam", "Subscriber")
```

Thank you!

Comment: So put the strings in escaped quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add escaped apostrophes:

```
'<a onclick="loadData(' + item.id + ', \'' + item.name + '\', \'' + item.description + '\')">' + item.name + '</a>'
```

As result you will get:

```
<a onclick="loadData(1, 'Sam', 'Subscriber')">Sam</a>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... this is what exactly I wanted

Answer (score 0):

You are answering yourself,

```
$(function() {
    $.each(json, function(i, item) {
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + item.id + '</td>' +
            '<td class="project-title"><a onclick="loadData(' + item.id + ', \"' + item.name + '\", \"' + item.description + '\")">' + item.name +
            '</a></td>' +
            '<td>' + item.description +
            '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
        $('#Table tbody').append(row);
    });
});
```